# p:Calendar conversion to Object

Tags: oracle, date, jsf, primefaces, mybatis

Hei there, I'm working on a primefaces application and in one of my composite components I'm trying to filter a table. TO achieve this I'm using a 'Clause' object that has a column-name, operator and value which will be stored in a map and sent to mybatis and limit the output of some selects.

I printed my results and the converter that I use in the p:calendar outputs this:

```
Ok FROM getAsString:     12/08/2014 00:00
```

but in my list of Clauses I get this:

`Clause [column=insDate, operator==, value=Tue Aug 12 00:00:00 EEST 2014, columnTitle=Creat la, type=2]`

So when I try to execute this in the persistence layer I get this:

#### SQL: SELECT *   FROM   SSLS_GUI.VW_ITEM             WHERE (              insDate =        TO_DATE(?,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI')            )

#### Cause: java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

This is the converter I was using and I decided that instead of a Date I'd return the formatted string. but I don't like the limitations (maybe in the future I ll want to change this and parse dates without HH:MI) so at this point I used return formatter.format(date); in the getAsObject function.

```
@ManagedBean
@FacesConverter(forClass = Date.class)
public class CalendarConverter implements Converter {

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        String value) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
    try {
        Date date = (Date) formatter.parse(value);
        System.out.println("OK FROM getAsObj:\t" + date.toString());
        return date;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION from getAsObj:\t");
    }
    return formatter;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        Object object) {
    try {
        if (object.toString().equals(" ") || object == null) {
            System.out.println("IS NULL");
            return null;
        } else {
            String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
                    .format(object);
            System.out.println("Ok FROM getAsString:\t " + date);
            return date;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION From getAsString\t"
                + object.toString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

this is the p:dataTable usage:

```
                        <p:calendar
                        rendered="#{cc.attributes.controller.lazyModel.advFilters.dateSelect == true}"
                        value="#{cc.attributes.controller.lazyModel.advFilters.clause.value}"
                        pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" required="true"
                        converter="#{calendarConverter}" />
```

and this is part of the query:

```
<foreach item="clause" collection="params1" separator=" AND "
open="(" close=")">                 
    ${clause.column} ${clause.operator}
    TO_DATE(#{clause.value},'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI')
```